# Get rid of the bar in iPhone 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone-5

I am trying to display an image in iPhone 5 Simulator in xcode. I am using the UIImageView. There is a bar below. Look at the attached screenshot. How do I get rid of that bar ?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6 are still unreleased software.

Comment: What @borrrden said; this stuff is still under NDA.  Or, click the iphone-5 tag and see the other umpteen questions asking basically the same thing here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck show toolbar from the navigation controller.

Comment: I added [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES] but that did not help.

Comment: you have to duplicate that setting on your view controller

Comment: I am sorry, I did not quite get your suggestion. Can you please explain. I have set that in my ViewController.